# Error: 'Can't find shared library' while creating executable using pyInstaller

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller

I have been using **PyInstaller** to package python script. I have a script, say test.py,

I ran following script to create an executable:

```
python pyInstaller.py test.py
```

It creates an executables named test in a folder named test. But when I run as:

```
./test
```

It shows an error

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677359/pyinstaller-cannot-find-libpython2-7-so-when-making-binary

Comment: And this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyinstaller/Ld_JZ0vqo28